# CUDA NPP min-max returns wrong output

Tags: c++, cuda, npp

I'm using the following code to test the CUDA NPP min-max function.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuComplex.h"
#include <cufft.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <npp.h>

#define Nz 256
#define Ny 280

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct cudaDeviceProp p;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&p, 0);
    printf("Device Name: %s\n", p.name);
    
    Npp32f* d_img;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_img, Nz*Ny * sizeof(Npp32f));
    nppsSet_32f(1.0f, d_img, Nz*Ny);

    int BufferSize;
    Npp32f Max;
    Npp32f Min;
    nppsMinMaxGetBufferSize_32f(Nz*Ny,&BufferSize);
    
    Npp8u *pScratch;
    cudaMalloc((void **)(&pScratch), BufferSize);
    nppsMinMax_32f(d_img,Nz*Ny,&Min,&Max,pScratch);
    printf("Max:%g, Min:%g\n", (float)Max, (float)Min);
    
    cudaFree(d_img);
    cudaFree(pScratch);
}
```

All elements in the device array are set to 1, but I get the following output.

```
Max:1.12104e-44, Min:0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to the [NPP documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/general_conventions_lb.html), `Min` and `Max` must be **stored on the device memory** (or at least accessible from the device) and not on the host memory like in your code. On way to fix that is to allocate some memory to store the min/max values and then transfer the values back to the host to print them like in the documentation example.